# Getting this error after installing PowerShell v6.3 Type "Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Controls.IsePluginStrip, Cognifide.PowerShell" not found

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am hoping to understand the cause of this and hopefully find a solution - I have looked at every possible solution, but haven't been able to fix it.

Sitecore v10.0.2 using PowerShell v6.3.

- I have installed Sitecore PowerShell extension v6.3 first in my local to see if its working
  properly, it was installed correctly & functionality was working correctly.
- Once it was working properly , I compared the list of files which was installed in the
  PowerShell package & took those files to the upper environment & pasted the files to the CM
  website folder. But then I was getting this below error.
- When I checked my local bin folder there was no file with the name of Cognifide.Powershell, I
  extracted the PowerShell zip also , it was not there as well.
- What could be the cause of it?

> An instance of Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.WebControls.RibbonStrip was null.
> Additional information: Type
> "Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Controls.IsePluginStrip,
> Cognifide.PowerShell" not found.

Comment: 1. Did you install on top of the older SPE? 2. Which package exactly did you install and where did you take it from?

Comment: Yes I Installed it on top of existing SPE. But I removed all the existing references of older SPE , before installing the new SPE. I took the package from this URL https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases

Comment: This issue only happens if you have older files still sitting around. You can look at the old package to see which file locations everything is stored.

Comment: @Harish If you installed package with "IAR" abbreviateion in name you picked the wrong one.